# IBM MQ installation Version 8

Tags: ibm-mq

In one of the windows system the administrator has installed the IBM MQ version 8. But after installation we are not ale to see the IBM MQ (installation 1) listed in the services. and also not able to see the file amqsvc.exe file.
If we launch Prepare Websphere MQ wizard it also just exits without any actions.

But on the control panel -programs and features able to see the IBM MQ installation1 is present . how to find out if the installation was done correctly?

Was this a MQ client installation instead of MQ server installation? how to find out what is the issue here as the MQ service is not present or its related files?

Comment: Look for dspmqver command.  This is present in both client and server.  The dspmq is only present in server.

Comment: dspmq is not present on the installation. this means the installation is a IBM MQ client?

Comment: If dspmqver is present but dspmq is not then yes it is a client.